# Check a number in Android Dialer

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to develop a dialer app for android for my company to make use of our internal voip system. i'm totally new to android, but have experience in titanium.

The app should capture the number and has to perform certain checks on the number. after the checks the standard phone app should dial the number.

Registering a broadcastreceiver is not an option, as this activity has to start on user input/decision

For this case I have an the following manifest:

```
<activity android:name="CallerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

that works as expected. My app shows up as a dialing option. and then in my activity I've the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Intent i = getIntent();
    final Uri number = i.getData();
    number = checkNumberInternal(number);

    Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
    dial.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(dial);
}
```

The code actually works, but the only problem is, that the default dial options dialog pops up again and again.

the app has to be without any UI

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine.  Use the below Code just before your application tag in the manifest file. Works fine now without opening the default call options popup.Let me know if u still find any issues:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: i do have this permisson set in the manifest file. the strange thing is that the application calls "itself" automatically as the code starts the dial activity